# I need a detailed step by step method to build a cursor in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is a cursor I am using, but I'd like to understand it and write my own.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertToTable1] (@list nvarchar(MAX))
   RETURNS @tbl TABLE (number varchar(1024) NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos        int,
           @nextpos    int,
           @valuelen   int

   SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

   WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex('.', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (number)
         VALUES (convert(int, substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
   return
end
```

Comment: There *is no* cursor in that code, its a simple loop ...

Comment: @Alex: which is essentialy a cursor in another form...

Comment: ok then if it is loop then could you please explain its functionality to me according to its code

Comment: Best option: just **never** ever use cursors - they're evil, they're annoying - and in 99% of the cases, they're not needed. Instead: learn to **think in sets** and use the set-based approach in SQL - that's the way one **should** go about programming SQL

Comment: @MitchWheat - Not really in this case. A cursor traverses rows. This is just a loop.

Comment: actulay i need to develope a query or a function to separate my ''csv's'' to the table and then call them separatly for the ''sp''

Comment: @marc_s please provide help link for "think in sets and use the set-based approach in SQL"

Comment: ya could you please elaborate your set based approach may be it will be a usefull thing

Comment: and one thing more could you guys please attach any link for the step by step guide to build a cursor or a while loop ???

Comment: @ChhatrapatiSharma: try these - [T-SQL Foundations: Thinking in Sets](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql/Thinking-in-Sets-129772) - 
[SQL Queries for Mere Mortals: Thinking in Sets](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1070897) -
[Thinking Set-Based .... or not?](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/30/thinking-set-based-or-not.aspx) - 
[Joe Celko's Thinking in Sets (book)](http://www.amazon.com/Joe-Celkos-Thinking-Sets-Management/dp/0123741378) - or just **Google** for *SQL thinking in sets* .....